# create windows service from jar file

Tags: java, service, installation

I have a java application which listen of port and accept incoming connection.it takes port number from flat file(config file).it requires some `.dll` to be placed in JRE folder to work.

i want to do it following way.

- Create .jar file (i have done it)
- Create .exe file or setup file (which will automatically place those `.dll` file in respective JRE path
- When setup finished auto start that `.jar` file as service which will run in background as windows service.

i have certain issues in 2 and 3 points. How can i create setup from `.jar` file ? which third party tool should i use ? at the end how can i start .exe as windows service ?

Comment: The point of java is to write once and run anywhere. What are you using the DLLs for? Maybe you can use a Java API to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: this library is used for serial communication `rxtx` name of dll is `rxtxSerial.dll`

Comment: It should not be necessary to slam the DLLs into the JRE folder -- and users are likely to strangle you if you mess with their basic system configuration that way. Set the paths properly instead, as part of the process of launching your Java code.

Comment: it is mentioned on their website http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_for_Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use tools like [Zero Install](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Install), [install4j](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) or [IzPack](http://izpack.org/) to create an installer (e.g. `.exe`) for all platforms you need. Those tools wrap your JAR file with a binary installer. Usually they also allow you to install/copy additional files such as your DLL.

Also, as raised by @keshlam in a comment, such installers can be configured to run your application with specific arguments (e.g. path to DLL).

Btw, have you thought about using [JavaComm instead of RxTx](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Java)?

Comment: i found rxtx is much faster than java comm

Comment: Fair enough...hope my answer was still helpful.